# C#/WPF: Idea how to display the last row of a ListView separately?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I've a ListView with about 10 GridViewColumn's and about 100 Lines/Row.
I'd like to display a "Total" or summary row at the bottom of the ListView.

Does anyone have a idea how to do that, with keeping the ColumnWidth etc. like the others and making it a separate item, so the "main" ListView can have a scrollbar?

I've uploaded here a mock-up (sorry for my bad graphic talent :-)):
[image](http://img245.imageshack.us/img245/7977/listviewexample.png)

Comment: @semirhage: What does that mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an example on how to have a listview with totals area at the end. The column width are binded between each column and its total

```
 <Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="Window1"
        x:Name="ctl"
        Height="300"
        Width="300"> 
  <Window.Resources>

    <GridViewColumnCollection x:Key="gvcc">
      <GridViewColumn Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=col1}"
                      Header="Date" />
      <GridViewColumn  Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=col2}"
                       Header="Day Of Week"
                       DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DayOfWeek}" />
      <GridViewColumn  Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=col3}"
                       Header="Year"
                       DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Year}" />

    </GridViewColumnCollection>
  </Window.Resources>
  
  <Grid>
    <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
               VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
               LastChildFill="True">
  

      <GridViewRowPresenter Name="listview_total"
                            DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" 
                            Margin="0,5,0,5"
                            Columns="{StaticResource gvcc}">
        <GridViewRowPresenter.Content>
          <sys:DateTime>2005/2/1</sys:DateTime>
        </GridViewRowPresenter.Content>
      </GridViewRowPresenter>
      

      
      <ListView x:Name="listview_rows" 
                SelectionMode="Single"
                DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListView.View>
          <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="col1"                            
                            Header="Date" />
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="col2"                            
                            Header="Day Of Week"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DayOfWeek}" />
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="col3"                            
                            Header="Year"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Year}" />
          </GridView>
        </ListView.View>

        <sys:DateTime>1/2/3</sys:DateTime>
        <sys:DateTime>4/5/6</sys:DateTime>
        <sys:DateTime>7/8/9</sys:DateTime>
        <sys:DateTime>10/11/12</sys:DateTime>
        <sys:DateTime>1/2/3</sys:DateTime>
        <sys:DateTime>4/5/6</sys:DateTime>
        <sys:DateTime>7/8/9</sys:DateTime>
        <sys:DateTime>10/11/12</sys:DateTime>
        <sys:DateTime>1/2/3</sys:DateTime>
        <sys:DateTime>4/5/6</sys:DateTime>
        <sys:DateTime>7/8/9</sys:DateTime>
        <sys:DateTime>10/11/12</sys:DateTime>
        <sys:DateTime>1/2/3</sys:DateTime>
        <sys:DateTime>4/5/6</sys:DateTime>
        <sys:DateTime>7/8/9</sys:DateTime>
        <sys:DateTime>10/11/12</sys:DateTime>
      </ListView>

    </DockPanel>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Building off [federubin's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1573817/203816), you can bind the `GridViewRowPresenter`'s `Columns` property directly to the `Columns` property of the `GridView`.

```
<GridViewRowPresenter Columns="{Binding ElementName=ListViewGridViewName, Path=Columns}" ...>
```

The columns' widths will be updated automatically in the presenter when they are changed in the main grid and you no longer have to duplicate your column definitions.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTestbed.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
  <Grid>
    <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" LastChildFill="True">

      <GridViewRowPresenter Columns="{Binding ElementName=ListViewGridView, Path=Columns}" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Margin="4,5,0,5">
        <GridViewRowPresenter.Content>
          <sys:DateTime>2005/2/1</sys:DateTime>
        </GridViewRowPresenter.Content>
      </GridViewRowPresenter>

      <ListView SelectionMode="Single" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListView.View>
          <GridView x:Name="ListViewGridView">
            <GridViewColumn Header="Date" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Day Of Week" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DayOfWeek}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Year" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Year}" />
          </GridView>
        </ListView.View>

        <sys:DateTime>1/2/3</sys:DateTime>
        <sys:DateTime>4/5/6</sys:DateTime>
        <sys:DateTime>7/8/9</sys:DateTime>
        <sys:DateTime>10/11/12</sys:DateTime>
        <sys:DateTime>1/2/3</sys:DateTime>
        <sys:DateTime>4/5/6</sys:DateTime>
        <sys:DateTime>7/8/9</sys:DateTime>
        <sys:DateTime>10/11/12</sys:DateTime>
        <sys:DateTime>1/2/3</sys:DateTime>
        <sys:DateTime>4/5/6</sys:DateTime>
        <sys:DateTime>7/8/9</sys:DateTime>
        <sys:DateTime>10/11/12</sys:DateTime>
        <sys:DateTime>1/2/3</sys:DateTime>
        <sys:DateTime>4/5/6</sys:DateTime>
        <sys:DateTime>7/8/9</sys:DateTime>
        <sys:DateTime>10/11/12</sys:DateTime>
      </ListView>

    </DockPanel>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2):

If your data source is a StaticResource, you can use a composite collection.  I really wish this would work elsewhere.  Sad, really.  Anyway it's really nice if you can use it.

```
<ListView>
   <ListView.ItemsSource>
      <CompositeCollection>
           <CollectionContainer Collection="{StaticResource MyCollection} />
           <ListViewItem>Last Item</ListViewItem>
      </CompositeCollection>
   </ListView.ItemsSource>
</ListView>
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

It almost seems like what you want is a second listview below the first one, with some way of keeping the column sizes in sync. Is there an event you can hook to let you know that the user has resized a particular column? (I'm not really a WPF person, but WinForms offers a ColumnSizeChanged and ColumnSizeChanging event.) It's a little gross, but unless you essentially roll your own custom listview control, I don't know if you're going to do much better.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I'm looking for.. thanks for the input, I think there isn't an "easier"/cleaner way (e.g. without Code-Behind/using seperate Events).