# Footer on ListView WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I would like to add a footer to the `ListView` with the sum of two columns in his respective columns, Licenses and Scans, I found something similar ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287979/c-wpf-idea-how-to-display-the-last-row-of-a-listview-separately)) but the footer is not being shown, if I add a 4 column into the `GridView`then the footer row is shown but without any values.
The `GridViewColumnHeader`contains a style which I would like to apply to the Footer as well (I have not pasted it to provide a Minimal, functional example)

This is the expected view:
[image]

xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:utils="Helper"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="450"
        Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ViewSource"
                              Source="{Binding DataList}">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="ToOrder" />
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewSource}}">
            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                        <DockPanel>
                                            <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
                                                <Grid.Resources>
                                                    <local:SumConverter x:Key="sumConverter" />
                                                </Grid.Resources>
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Col1, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Col2, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Col3, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                                                           Text="Sum: "
                                                           FontWeight="Bold" />
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                                                           Grid.Row="1"
                                                           Text="{Binding Path=Items, Converter={StaticResource sumConverter}, ConverterParameter=1}"/>
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2"
                                                           Grid.Row="1"
                                                           Text="{Binding Path=Items, Converter={StaticResource sumConverter}, ConverterParameter=2}"/>
                                                <Line Grid.Column="0"
                                                      Grid.Row="0"
                                                      Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                                      Stroke="Black"
                                                      X2="500"
                                                      Fill="Black"
                                                      VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                            </Grid>
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </DockPanel>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView x:Name="OverviewGridView">
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Date, StringFormat=dd.MM.yyyy}"
                                    Header="Date" 
                                    x:Name="Col1"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LicenseCount}"
                                    Header="Licenses" 
                                    x:Name="Col2"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ScansCount}"
                                    Header="Scans" 
                                    x:Name="Col3"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModel

```
namespace WpfApp2
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
    using WpfApp2.Annotations;

    public class OverView
    {
        public int ToGroup { get; set; } = 1;
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int LicenseCount { get; set; }
        public int ScansCount { get; set; }
    }

    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _totalLicenses;
        private ObservableCollection<OverView> _dataList;
        private int _totalScans;

        public ViewModel()
        {
            OverView a = new OverView
                             {
                                 Date = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0)),
                                 LicenseCount = 2,
                                 ScansCount = 7
                             };
            OverView b = new OverView
                             {
                                 Date = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(5, 0, 0, 0)),
                                 LicenseCount = 3,
                                 ScansCount = 2
                             };
            OverView c = new OverView { Date = DateTime.Now, LicenseCount = 5, ScansCount = 4 };
            OverView d = new OverView
                             {
                                 Date = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0)),
                                 LicenseCount = 1,
                                 ScansCount = 3
                             };

            DataList = new ObservableCollection<OverView> { a, b, c, d };

            TotalLicenses = DataList.Sum(overview => overview.LicenseCount);
            TotalScans = DataList.Sum(overview => overview.ScansCount);
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public ObservableCollection<OverView> DataList
        {
            get => _dataList;
            set
            {
                _dataList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public int TotalLicenses
        {
            get => _totalLicenses;
            set
            {
                _totalLicenses = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public int TotalScans
        {
            get => _totalScans;
            set
            {
                _totalScans = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) =>
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

SumConverter

```
namespace WpfApp2
{
    #region Using

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Windows.Data;

    #endregion

    public class SumConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            if (value is IEnumerable<object> total)
            {
                foreach (object o in total)
                {
                    if (o is OverView overview)
                    {
                        int col = int.Parse((string)parameter);

                        sum += col == 1 ? overview.LicenseCount : overview.ScansCount;
                    }
                }

                return sum;
            }

            return 0;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) => 1;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit, after further test, I had kind of success creating a new Property in the Overview object to group by it, then use a converter to sum the columns I need.
This is the result: The code is updated with the solution.
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I get where you are showing the information in the ui. Did you mean to add the sum as a row to the Datalist? Because that is not happening. Or did you mean to place ui elements in your xaml below the grid to show the totals from your viewmodel? Because I don't see that happening in the xaml either. Am I missing something?

Comment: Exactly the second, I need to show another row below the GridView with the sum of the columns LicenseCount and ScanCount

Comment: I have updated my question to add the expected view

Comment: Did you consider adding a "sum" item to your `DataList` collection that displays the sum of the columns?

Comment: Ok, I see the update. But where is the Columns property that your Path points to?

Comment: @mm8 That would work, but then I would not be able to apply the same style I have in the header (I have not add the style for simplicity)..

Comment: @Arwin That is given by the `OverviewGridView`

Comment: I have updated my question with the "solution" which I dont like it some much but does the work.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot integrate it into the listview but you can put it below like this:

```
            <StackPanel>
                <GridViewRowPresenter DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                              Content="Sum"
                              Columns="{Binding ElementName=OverviewGridView, Path=Columns}">
                </GridViewRowPresenter>
                <ListView
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding DataList}">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView x:Name="OverviewGridView">
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Date}" Header="Date"/>
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LicenseCount}" Header="Licenses"/>
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ScansCount}" Header="Scans"/>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=OverviewGridView, Path=Columns[0].ActualWidth}"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=OverviewGridView, Path=Columns[1].ActualWidth}"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=OverviewGridView, Path=Columns[2].ActualWidth}"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="Summe" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataList, FallbackValue=0,Converter={StaticResource Summierer}, ConverterParameter=1}"  Margin="10,0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataList, FallbackValue=0,Converter={StaticResource Summierer}, ConverterParameter=2}"  Margin="10,0" Grid.Column="2"/>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
```

[image]

this is my converter (needs rewriting!! I didnt put any effort in it)

```
 public class SummUp: IValueConverter
{
    #region Convert
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var rtn = 0;
        var coll = (value as ObservableCollection<OverView>);
        var param = System.Convert.ToInt32(parameter);
        foreach (var item in coll)
        {
            if (param == 1)
            {
                rtn += item.LicenseCount;
            }
            else if (param == 2)
            {
                rtn += item.ScansCount;
            }
        }

        return rtn;
    }//END Convert
    #endregion Convert

    #region ConvertBack
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }//END ConvertBack 
    #endregion ConvertBack 

}//END class boolToNotVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
```

Comment: I have thought about that before, but I saw this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287979/c-wpf-idea-how-to-display-the-last-row-of-a-listview-separately and that produces what I am asking for, A fix last row with the Total, but in that example they are doing it with only one value and that is my problem I believe.